# Node.js path: Resolve relative paths

Tags: node.js, path

Given this folder structure:

```
content/
  folder/
    1.md
    2.md
```

and the Node.js process running in the root of the structure.

I have these pieces of information available:

```js
// path to the content folder
const dir = 'content'; 

// path to the current file
const filepath = 'folder/1.md';

// A link relative to the current file
const href = './2.md';
```

Which combination of Node.js [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) methods will give me the result `folder/2.md`? I want to resolve the relative `href` to a path in the content folder.

I think I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

**P.S.**: The larger context is that I'm working on a static site generator and would like to replace in the Markdown any relative links to other Markdown documents with their URL, and for that I need a `href` relative to the content folder to look it up.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? The problem isn't very clear. Do you mean if ```filepath=folder/2.md``` how to get ```href=./1.md``` and ```dir=content``` using ```path```?

Comment: I think you solved the problem for me in the answer you deleted. I was confused by the fact that `join('folder/1.md', './2.md')` would not result in `folder/2.md` but `folder/1.md/2.md`. `dirname()` was the key! I will elaborate the question, for posterity.

Comment: Sure thing. Just as a courtesy to people of the future, could you amend it to not include `dir`, a.k.a. `content`? Turns out it's not necessary to include it for things to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
const path = require("path");

const filepath = "folder/1.md";
const href = "./2.md";

console.log(path.join(path.dirname(filepath), href)); // folder/2.md
```